# Union 50+ tables with different number of columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, union, union-all

I have over 50 different tables which I would like to combine into one big table.  All the tables have a different number of columns.

Currently, to union the tables together, I am writing an individual select statement for each of the tables, and inserting a null column if that column doesn't exist in the table. Then I am using UNION ALL to union them together.

For example:

```
(
select col1
        , null as col2 
        , col3
 from   table1

union all

 select col1
       , col2
       , null as col
from   table2
)
```

Although this works, it is very manual and time consuming. Is there a better, more efficient way to union these tables into one? As with over 50 tables, I am going to have thousands of lines of code.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Surely, you are not stitching together some unrelated table schemas just for fun.

Comment: Oh sorry. The tables are all related and they refer to the same data, but not all columns are in all tables due to the way the original data was extracted. I am trying to create one big table which appends all tables into 1 so that I can query the data on the whole. However, I can't just select certain columns because there are some columns missing from certain tables which I actually need to query.

Comment: Is this a one off query?  Once you have all the data, in one table, will you need to run again?

Comment: It is just a one off query, there should be no need to re-run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query SQL Server metadata, and from the result dynamically construct a SQL statement. This can be done in any programming language, including T-SQL itself.

Here's a rough example; execute this query, copy/paste the result back into the query window, and execute that.

If the 50 tables have similar names (e.g. all start with `Foo`), then you can replace the exhaustive table list (`WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')` in my example) by `WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Foo%'`.

```
WITH
    AllTables (TABLE_NAME) AS (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')
    ),
    TablesWithSelectors (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Selector) AS (
        SELECT t.TABLE_NAME, a.COLUMN_NAME, CASE WHEN b.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'NULL AS ' ELSE '' END + a.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM AllTables t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM AllTables)) a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON b.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME AND b.COLUMN_NAME = a.COLUMN_NAME
    ),
    SelectStatements (Sql) AS (
        SELECT
            'SELECT ' +
            STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + Selector
                FROM TablesWithSelectors
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = r.TABLE_NAME
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
            , 1, 2, '') +
            ' FROM ' +
            TABLE_NAME
        FROM TablesWithSelectors r
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
    )
SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ' UNION ALL ' + sql
        FROM SelectStatements
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 11, '')
```

Thanks to:
[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: FYC, I refined the query, adding a final concatenation step. Now the result is really the finished query.